# detecting button without touch sense in android

Tags: android

I have 8 buttons I would like the app to detect the buttons by just scrolling on the screen and not by touching? like the accessibility feature in Jelly bean? I am not sure how to call that feature as? Gesture? Motion sense?

Is this possible? What should I look for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the UI elements in Android are focusable by scrollballs, arrow keys, etc...  The Views have an View.setOnFocusChangedListener callback.  You can also set focus on elements programmatically.

Some example code I quickly wrote and did not test.

```
float initialX = 0;
float initialY = 0;
int currentFocusedChild = 0;
List<View> children;

public void walkElements() {
    final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    children = mainLayout.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = event.getX();
                    initialY = event.getY();                        
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float diffX = event.getX() - initialX;
                    float diffY = event.getY() - initialY;

                    if(diffY > 0) {
                        if (currentFocusedChild < children.size() - 1) {
                            currentFocusedChild++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (currentFocusedChild > 0) {
                            currentFocusedChild--;
                        }
                    }
                    children.get(currentFocusedChild).setSelected(true);

                    //Sleep for a period of time so the selection is slow enough for the user.
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    children.get(currentFocusedChild).performClick();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: We are not using scroll here...I think I have to re-phrase what I am saying - To open a a button we touch on the screen on corresponding button right instead of that I want to just touch the screen once without removing my hand I want to scroll on the screen to get to the next button. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to implement an onTouchGestureListener on the root view, keep track of the ACTION_DOWN event with X/Y positions and then iterate through the children of the view looking for focusable items.

Comment: Thanks Ty S. Do you have any link and examples that people have done?

Comment: Thanks Ty S. The code is perfect but the problem is if I want to play a sound for different buttons - it plays only one sound when I touch the screen on specific location and after that the buttons are not detected or the sound doesn't play? - Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You'd probably want to set an onSelected or onFocused listener on the buttons to play the sound when it is selected.  Or you could subclass Button and write your own behavior when it's selected.